# model not getting set while using render helper in ember -cli

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, render, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli and there is one controller which gets using a render helper and hence no route. Example

```
{{render 'ref-type' ref-type}}
```

Now inside the controller ref-type

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions{
        isShown: function() {
            var m = this.get('model'); //here model is undefined can i know why?
        }
    }
});
```

and model ref-type is

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    getData: function(){
        return 'xyz';   //data is returned hre
    }
});
```

why am i not able to access model in the controller.

Adding a raw JSBin example
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/AJoyOGo/364/edit?html,js,console,output)
Should the model always be DS.Model.extend? i do not think so.

Also Instead of ref-type i have used 'sample' as the name, so that it is easier to understand

Comment: Can you provide complete example in JSBin?

Comment: its very difficult since i am using ember cli and not just ember js

Comment: I think this is not ember-cli issue. Where do you initialize your model that referenced in {{render 'ref-type' ref-type}}

Comment: its definitely not ember-cli issue. I have my code in ember-cli so diff to put it in jsbin.
The call in {{render 'ref-type' ref-type}} should itself do the assignment. There is no separate initialization in ember-cli. It is taken care while building it

Comment: @Wishy its actually not hard at all to make a small JSBin to show your problem when using ember cli. Just follow the old naming conventions. It is impossible to tell what your problem is right now. You have a method called getData but nowhere is this method invoked. You have a call to this.get('model') but you have no route shown. Where is this model property being set? Is it on another route? We would need to see that route then to see if you are properly setting up the model. Who is calling isShown? What is 'ref-type' template? what is the ref-type object? Where is it created?

Comment: @sunrize920 you are right!!! I will get a jsbin ready as soon as possible

Comment: @sunrize920 added the jsbin example

Comment: @saygun added the jsbin example

Comment: FYI controller initializes before you go to that route...try some other  hooks like activate, afterModel to get the model object

Comment: @CodeJack Are you sure? The ember guides state that the order of execution is route first and then controller

Comment: @CodeJack also here route is not being used. The template and controller are called through {{render}} and not url

Comment: ok partially my bad...but still if you want to access in `init` of controller may be try to access after calling `this._super()`..

Comment: @CodeJack Even though that information is not required here thanks i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize your model. According to your JSBin example you must have property named `sample` in your TodosController. `ember` will not create an object by itself. I have edited your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gadegufajebo/1/edit). It might not be the best approach but I tried to explain what is going on.

If you put log `{{log sample}}` just above your `render` helper you will notice that your sample property is already undefined.

Comment: ahhh right are you sure thats how it is???You are saying {{render "sample" sample}} is like {{sample-component sampleVal = sample}} where sample is a value of current context either from model or from controller? I thought the model sample in {{render "sample" sample}} is not context specific. I thought it just loaded a sample model rather than take it from the current context. Btw are you sure of that?

Comment: Also do you know how i can initialize a model when route is not involved but {{render}} is used?

Comment: Yes ember cannot create model for {[render "sample" sample}} you should provide that model.

I don't know your application logic but due to my JSBin example I suggest you to create that "sample" model in setupController hook of TodosRoute. 

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model); 
  controller.set('sample', Todos.sample.create());
}